# Getting ODBC connection results as ruby object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, odbc

I've had to add an ODBC connection to a remote mysql server into my app.

This is the first time I've done something like this.

I was expecting the results to return as a ruby object, just like the rest of the ActiveRecord requests.

However, I'm beginning to think that maybe ODBC isn't handled the same way through the ruby-odbc gem.

When I output a debug statement on my models which connect through a standard connection, I get the standard

```
--- !ruby/object:ModelName 
attributes:
   etc.etc.
```

but when I output a debug statement on the model connected through the ODBC, i get

```
[#<ModelName modelID: 1, name: "name" etc. etc. ]
```

Is there any way for me to get ODBC connections working like the rest of my models?

#### UPDATE

To clarify, I am hoping to get the data as an object so I can get the data like

```
<%= @something.name %>
```

With the way I'm getting the data back now, I can't refer to it as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's returning an array of objects, instead of just one. If you only want a single object, just add `.first` to the result.